# How to select custom compiler "Tool chain" in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, gcc, qt-creator, cross-compiling, mingw32

I have Qt Creator on my mac. I downloaded the Qt sdk sources, I built them, and I am able to compile code for mac and it runs fine.

I would like to target Windows, so I downloaded mingw32 sources, I built them, and now I have a `i386-mingw32-g++` executable that compiles c++ code just fine, and the binary executable compiled from my mac runs just fine on a Windows box.

I would like now to create a new build configuration in Qt Creator so that it will use mingw32 as the compiler, in order to generate Windows binaries.

Here's what I got in the Tool Chains configuration window:

[image: Tool Chains configuration window]

Here's what I have in my build configuration:

[image: Build configuration Tool Chains options]

As you can see I am not able to select mingw32 as the compiler. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your Qt libraries are Mac version. Creator knows the target platform of selected Qt install and shows only the tool chains that work with it.

I don't know how you can install a Windows version of Qt on a Mac. The installer obviously won't work. The only possible path is to build Qt with mingw that you have built.

Edit: Here's some info on cross-compiling Windows libs: http://lists.qt.nokia.com/pipermail/qt-interest/2011-March/031945.html